# Splitting a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, gaussian

I want to split any matrix (most likely will be a 3x4) into two. One part will be the left hand and then the right hand - only the last column.

```
[[1,0,0,4],              [[1,0,0],       [4,
 [1,0,0,2],     ---> A=   [1,0,0],   B =  2,
 [4,3,1,6]]               [4,3,1]]        6]
```

Is there a way to do this in python and assign then as A and B?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do like this:

```
def split_last_col(mat):
    """returns a tuple of two matrices corresponding 
    to the Left and Right parts"""
    A = [line[:-1] for line in mat]
    B = [line[-1] for line in mat]
    return A, B

split_last_col([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

#### output:

```
([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]], [3, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create A and B manually, like this:

```
def split(matrix):
  a = list()
  b = list()

  for row in matrix:
    row_length = len(row)
    a_row = list()

    for index, col in enumerate(row):
      if index == row_length - 1:
        b.append(col)
      else:
        a_row.append(col)
    a.append(a_row)
  return a, b
```

Or using lists comprehension:

```
def split(matrix):
  a = [row[:len(row) - 1] for row in matrix]
  b = [row[len(row) - 1] for row in matrix]
  return a, b
```

Example:

```
matrix = [
 [1, 0, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 2],
 [4, 3, 1, 6]
]

a, b = split(matrix)

print("A: %s" % str(a)) # Output ==> A: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [4, 3, 1]]
print("B: %s" % str(b)) # Output ==> B: [4, 2, 6]
```